# ESP8266 on WiFi without password, possible?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

Is it possible to connect to an SSID that does not require a password?
My project using ESP8266-01 modules will sometimes be used in non-password protected guest networks.

Comment: yes, just skip the password. it works.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it works! You can use:

```
WiFi.begin(ssid, NULL)
```

or even leave the passphrase empty, because it is optional:

```
WiFi.begin(ssid)
```

Reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiBegin